# Debug Android application on phone using Netbeans

Tags: android, debugging, netbeans, motorola-droid

I recently built a new PC, got the latest android SDK, Netbeans 7.1, java SDK, etc installed so I could debug my android apps.  When my phone was connected to my old PC via USB I could simply run my app in Netbeans and it would automatically send it to my phone for debugging.  All my phone settings are the same (install 3rd party apps: true, allow USB debugging: true) and I've upgraded all my app projects to the latest SDK version in Netbeans, so those aren't the issues.  In addition, I've got the Motorola Droid X device drivers installed.  I tried installing just the Motorola ADB interface driver but doing so it tells me a newer version is already available.

Can anyone help shed some light on what else I need to do to make Netbeans send the running app to my phone instead of starting the emulator?  Thanks!

EDIT: The device does appear when I run "adb devices"

Comment: does the device appear in the list when you type "adb devices" in a cmd shell?  (This is assuming you have sdk tools in your PATH)

Comment: I knew I forgot to mention something.  Yes, it appears.  Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what fixed it, but I think one of the gotchas of netbeans/android is it doesn't give a great error message when it's time for you to uninstall the debug version of the app on your device.  Once I did this it deployed just fine on my phone.